# Google Cloud Network Admin vs Network User permission gap clarification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Maybe a silly question but I can't get out of it.
In Google Cloud a Shared VPC supports amongst others the major roles: Shared VPC Admin and Service Project Admin. Furthermore is advisable to define a Network Admin to administer networks in an Host Project:

[IAM Roles in Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#iam_in_shared_vpc)

What looks hard to understand for me is that while Google states:

> Important: The Network Admin role does not include all of the permissions in the Network User role. IAM > members having only the Network Admin role do not have permission to use the host project or subnets in > its Shared VPC networks.

when I look to the single permissions of Network Admin vs Network User at:

[Compute Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles)

I do not see what permission is relevant to create VMs in a Subnet that the Network Admin does NOT contain whereas the Network User does! Apparently to me it looks like that the Network Admin contains by far more that what Network User does. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the compute engine roles you linked, the specific permission you would need compute.instances.create to create VMs at all. So if a user just has Network Admin as a role, they could create and manage network related resources but cannot create VMs, so they would need another role that allows them to do this.

Also, although it seems like Network admin has more permissions over all, there are a few permissions that the Network User has that Network Admin does not.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The permission you mention compute.instances.create is just missing in the NetworkUser's. According to Google the NetworkUser should be able to create a VM.This is exactly my problem; unless I am looking in the wrong source.

Comment: Neither role has that permission. Network user is just supposed to be able to use networks/resources and not really create them. Where are you seeing that it should have instances.create?

Comment: Ok but isn't strange? Any IAM role in GCP has a list of associated permission (a role is nothing else than set of permissions). So I am wondering that "Network user is just supposed to be able to use networks/resources and not really create them". I trust you but I do not see consistency with general concept of IAM roles. Naturally I should analyse a role checking the associated permission list to understand what it can and cannot do. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Ok I see what you're seeing now. 
"For example, a network user can create a VM instance that belongs to a host project network"
This is a little misleading because the user itself does not have the permission. I imagine they meant that if the user does have the permission from another role they would be able to use the shared VPCs from the host project and create VMs on those networks.

It probably could have been worded better.

Comment: Exactly. So that said I do not see anything that NetworkUser can do that NetworkAdmin cannot. Hence to me the statement from Google "Important: The Network Admin role does not include all of the permissions in the Network User role. IAM members having only the Network Admin role do not have permission to use the host project or subnets in its Shared VPC networks."  is likely wrong or misleading.

Comment: Seems like there isn't a permission that the User has that the Admin doesn't. I've filed for google to update their doc.

Answer (score 0):

The Network Admin role provides permissions to:
Only List the available firewall rules.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29826102)